# Concentration bound on function of the estimate

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, information-theory, concentration-of-measure

I know that through concentration inequalities (e.g. Hoeffding, Mcdiarmids, Chernoff) it is possible to have concentration bounds on the empirical mean $\hat{\mu}(N) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N X_i$ of $N$ i.i.d. Random Variables $X_1,...,X_N$ of the type
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\mathbb{E}[X]-\hat{\mu}(N) \geq \varepsilon \right] \leq 1-\delta 
$$

**I want to find a concentration bound on $f(\hat{\mu}(N))$**
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\mathbb{E}[f(X)]-f(\hat{\mu}(N)) \geq \varepsilon \right] \leq 1-\delta 
$$
where $f(\cdot)$ is a non-linear function, possibly with smoothness assumption (e.g. $L$-Lipschitz). Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a back-of-envelop computation. Someone else should please check that I haven't screwed anything. Also, I'm not certain we need to impose tail bounds on $X$ (e.g sub-Gaussianity) as I've done below...

---

So lat $X$ be a random vector in $\mathbb R^p$ (the scalar case corresponds to $p=1$) with mean $E[X] = \mu \in \mathbb R^p$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ (a $p$-by-$p$ psd matrix). Let $\hat{\mu}_N := (1/N)\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$, where $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ are $N$ iid copies of $X$.

The triangle inequality, one computes

$$
\begin{split}
|E[f(X)] - f(\hat{\mu}_N)| &= |E[f(X)] - f(X) + f(X) - f(\mu) + f(\mu) -  f(\hat{\mu}_N)|\\
&\le |E[f(X)] - f(X)| + |f(X) - f(\mu)| + |f(\mu)-f(\hat{\mu}_N)|
\end{split}
\tag{*}
$$

Now,

> Suppose $X$ is $\sigma$-subGaussian and $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz.

Then, with probability $\ge 1 - \delta$, it holds that
$$
\begin{split}
(1/L)|f(\mu)-f(\hat{\mu}_N)| &\le \|\mu-\hat{\mu}_n\| \le \sqrt{\frac{\text{Tr}(\Sigma)}{N}} + \sqrt{\frac{2\lambda_\max(\Sigma)\log(1/\delta)}{N}}\\
&= \mathcal O(\sqrt{d\log(1/\delta)/N}).
\end{split}
$$

Thus by (*), asymptotically in $N$, we have

$$
\begin{split}
P(|E[f(X)] - f(\hat{\mu}_N)| > \epsilon) &\le P(|E[f(X)] - f(X)| > \frac{\epsilon}{3}) + P(|f(X) - f(\mu)| > \frac{\epsilon}{3})\\
&\quad\quad + P(|f(\mu)-f(\hat{\mu}_N)| > \frac{\epsilon}{3})\\
&\le A_1e^{-C_1\epsilon^2} + A_2e^{-C_2\epsilon^2} + \mathcal O(1/\sqrt{N}),
\end{split}
$$

for some positive absolute constants $A_1,A_2,A,C_1,C_2,C$.

The first term in the above bound is by concentration of Lipschitz functions of subGaussian vectors and and the second is because $|f(X) - f(\mu)| \le L\|X-\mu\|$ and using (again!) the subGaussianity of $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! How is it possible to determine the constants?

Comment: You may take $A_1 = A_2 = A_3 = 2$ and $A = 3\max(A_1,A_2,A_3) = 6$. Finally, you may take $C = \frac{1}{4\sigma^2}\min(1,1/L^2)$ (or something like that, I guess ...). I don't have time to work out the precise values of the constants, but here is how it goes: The first term is concentraiton of Lipschitz functions of subGaussian variables; the second term is since $|f(X)-f(\mu)| \le L\|X-\mu\|$ (then use subGaussianity of $X$); the 3rd term is standard Gaussian concentration. This should help you estimate all the constants...

Comment: Actually, the 3rd term in my bound can (and should) be treated more carefully: It can be reduced to a tail bound like $P(\|\hat{\mu}_N-\mu\| > \frac{\epsilon}{3L})$ and bounded nonasymptotically (i.e for all $n$, large or small!) by something like $A_4\exp(-C_4(n/\lambda_\max(\Sigma))(\epsilon/(3L)-\text{trace}(\Sigma)/\sqrt{n})_+^2$. See Theorem 1 of this paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ejs/1488423803. As I said, this was just a back-of-envelop calculation. I'll find some time soon to write everything down more carelly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very useful answer again!

Comment: Why is it possible to split the initial inequality >t into 3 parts of t/3 tail bound?

Comment: By triangle inequality, $|a-d| \le |a-b| + |b - c| + |c-d|$. Thus, for the $|a-d|$ to be greater than $t$ (call this event $E$), at least one of those three terms must be greater than $t/3$ (call these events $E_1$, $E_2$, and $E_3$ resp.), i.e $E \subseteq E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3$. Now, use union bound to get

$$
P(E) \le P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3) \le P(E_1) + P(E_2) + P(E_3).
$$